# How can i know if ionic,angular are properly installed. basic work like interpolation isnt working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
  <button (click)="onChangeText()">nothing</button>
    <ionic-button>see</ionic-button>
```

the first line is an event on button which doesnt work. 2nd line is just button also not working

Comment: please post complete code not just fragments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a "package.json" file and find **"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9"** or other version and framework in the dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
"@capacitor/app": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/core": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.2.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

},